# UIPATH - how to check if an Excel file is on "Read only" mode or not

Tags: readonly, uipath

I want to use UIPATH to open and make changes to Excel files that are located on a shared network. If one of the files opened by my Bot is already in use by another user, it's opened in "Read only" mode and does not allow saving of the modifications.

How can I check with UIPATH if the file is in "Read only" mode or not to make a new rules about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Get File Info activity and then use the **.IsReadOnly** property to find out.

[image]

**Then:**

[image]